# java linkedlist string sort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

So, I have several lists of word pairs and I need to sort them in ascending or descending order. The method I'm using right now is the insertion sort algorithm. And this seems to work fine for the smaller lists. But every time I try to sort a large list, it freezes, with no errors. I tried to see what was going on by debugging with printing out "a was swapped for b"
and you can see it start working and it slows down and eventually stops like the computer just said, "there's too many, I give up". My question is, is there something wrong with my code, or do I simply need to use a more efficient method, and if so, which one and what would it look like?

```
for (int j=0; j < wordpair_list.size()-1; j++){
    for (int i=0; i < wordpair_list.size()-1; i++){
        String wordA_1 = wordpair_list.get(i).getWordA();
        String wordA_2 = wordpair_list.get(i+1).getWordA();

        if (wordA_1.compareToIgnoreCase(wordA_2) < 0){
            WordPair temp = wordpair_list.get(i);
            wordpair_list.set(i,wordpair_list.get(i+1));
            wordpair_list.set(i+1, temp);           
        }
    }
}
```

that's for descending. all i do for ascending is swap the '>' in the if statement to '<'

Comment: What number of elements are we talking about? dozens? hundreds? millions?

Comment: Also, from looking at it briefly - that looks more like a bubble sort than insertion sort to me

Comment: Some `List` implementations can be slow being accessed to (maybe are you using `Vector`?) Since the size of the list does not change, I would implement this logic using arrays (or at the very least, an `ArrayList`)

Comment: @amit - thousands. also i apologize if i don't know the difference. still in college and just learned about insertion sort, so that's what i was going for.

Comment: @SJuan76 - the LinkedList is a variable of an unknown size.

Comment: As long as its size does not change in your algorithm, you can always convert it to an array. In fact there is a `toArray()` operation in the `List` interface.

Comment: Why not use the built in sort methods with a suitable comparator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are performing bubble sort. As others have pointed out, performing get() and set() operations are expensive with linked lists.

I am not conversant with Java, but it appears that you can use ListIterators to carry out bubble sort in O(N^2)

> ListIterator listIterator(int index) Returns a list-iterator of the
>   elements in this list (in proper sequence), starting at the specified
>   position in the list. Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the
>   specified index is is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size()).

For bubble sort, you just need to swap the adjacent elements, so you can iterate through the list like an array and keep swapping if needed.

Moreover, you can skip the section of the list that is already sorted. Take a look at a good bubble sort algorithm.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Yup, the ListIterator allows add and remove from arbitrary places in a LinkedList in constant time (assuming the iterator is already at that position). OP should have used an array though :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not insert sort, this is closer to bubble sort. Second, there is nothing wrong with your code, but as expected for this sorting algorithm it is quadratic. Thus for larger input it may take a long time to finish(e.g. for 200 000 elements it may take several minutes).

EDIT: as you are using List the complexity is even higher - up to cubic. As `set` in a list is not constant. You may try to implement the algorithm with Array to save this added complexity.

Comment: It seems more of a bubble sort to me.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal argh ... true. I was mislead a bit by the code. Will fix that

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that insertion sort is already O(N^2) algorithm, the access (both get and set) to the item in the linked list by the item index is O(N) operation, making your code O(N^3), in other words *extremely slow*.

Basically, you have two options:

- copy the linked list into a temp array, sort an array using your algorithm (array access by index is O(1), overall algorithm will stay at O(N^2) (unless you choose a better one), create a new sorted linked list from the array.
- use some other algorithm that does not need indexed access (for example, it is actually possible to implement insertion sort without indexed operations because you can swap two adjacent items in the linked list, through you will have to use a linked list implementation where you have direct access to the "previous" and "next" links).